# How to remove || expressions from end of string using regex on notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have strings which look like this

```php
न च <तुल्य-गुणः>K1  दूष्यः  न दोषः प्रकृतिः भवेत्|| 11 ||
उक्ताः  महाचतुष्पादे येषु आयत्तं <भिषक्-जितम्>T3|| 24 ||
```

My goal is to remove the digits and the || symbol they are contained within at the end of the string. I tried using this expression `\|\|[0-9.]+\|\|` but it only worked for a few of the instances. What expression can I try? Please note I am doing this on Notepad++.

Comment: `\|\|\s*\d+\s*\|\|`. You could also use a space character in place of `\s` in case of false positives.

Comment: Try this with `match-case `  unchecked ....find: `T3\K.{0,}` replace with: `nothing`

Comment: Or if the T1 T2 T3 is incremental  then use `T\d+\K.{0,}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only concerned about the end of the string, you'll want to use `$`

so try: `(\s*\|\| [\d]* \|\|)$` and replace with empty textbox.

[image]

after click `Replace All`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```php
\|\|(?:\h+\d+\h+\|\|)+$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/AOUmGq/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \h+                      horizontal whitespace (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \h+                      horizontal whitespace (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```